# Single quotes within json value

Tags: javascript, json, formatting

Javascript fails to read this json string as it contains a single quote character which it sees as the end of the string.

How can I escape the single quote so that it is not seen as the end of the string?

```
var json = '{"1440167924916":{"id":1440167924916,"type":"text","content":"It's a test!"}}';

var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: Why are you writing out an object serialized as JSON, then decoding it on the next line? Just write an object literal. There's no need to put your object in a string at all.

Comment: Funny when someone asks an easy js question how there's a flood of equivalent answers within the same minute. This is surely a duplicate.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. The problem is that you have a single quote in a JavaScript string literal delimited with single quotes. The fact the string contains JSON is beside the point. (Why are you writing a static string of JSON and then parsing it anyway, why not just remove the quotes  from around the edge and treat it as a JavaScript object literal?)

Comment: @Fuser97381 It's not written out, the value is coming from a database and put there by php.

Comment: @ezero — Why are you writing PHP that does that then?

Comment: @Quentin So that a javascript object can be built up and then stored in a database as a json string which can then later be re-assembled as the same object.

Comment: And why do you need to generate a string literal of JSON and then parse it with JavaScript instead of treating that JSON as an object literal?

Comment: @Quentin How could I treat the JSON as an object literal?

Comment: But not putting it inside a string literal. i.e. removing the quotes. Just like  Fuser97381 said in the first comment.

Comment: Also, php has `json_encode`, which you should be using if you need to go from a variable to JSON in php.

Comment: @Quentin I was not aware that was possible, thanks!

Comment: @Fuser97381 I was already using json_encode. Using the json to create an object without first turning it into a string was the solution.

Comment: So basically the real solution to your weird question is that you should have been calling `json_encode` twice, since the second one would have escaped the values of the string representation.

Comment: @Fuser97381 No, that was not the solution. It was simply to remove the outer single quotes before php outputted the json.

Comment: json_encode would also escape the double quotes

Comment: He's providing you samples of what's happing and how to reproduce it - which surely you would have complained about if he hadn't. Think a bit more abstractly about it. There's a single apostrophe in the data. Maybe a better question would be "How should I encode this data to eliminate problems with the apostrophe?"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a backslash to [escape the character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation):

```
var json = '{"1440167924916":{"id":1440167924916,"type":"text","content":"It\'s a test!"}}';
var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: Using a backslash is an example of 'escaping' a character. See more information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp)

Comment: This answers the question I posted. However, the solution I used was to create an object literal directly from the json instead of first turning it into a string by simply removing the outer single quotes. Thanks to Quentin for pointing that out.

Comment: He's providing sample data. He's not actually writing out value literals. He probably wants something more global in nature, and not somewhere where he has to run every string value through an explicit escapeThisApostrophe(...) function, which would be horribly inefficient and dumb.

Answer (score 6):

Just escape the single quote with a backslash such as `\'`:

```js
var json = '{"1440167924916":{"id":1440167924916,"type":"text","content":"It\'s a test!"}}';

var parsed = JSON.parse(json);

//Output parsed to the document using JSON.stringify so it's human-readable and not just "[object Object]":
document.write(JSON.stringify(parsed));
```

Comment: That's great for his sample data; that's not a real world fix.

Answer (score 1):

Escape it with a backslash

```
var json = '{"1440167924916":{"id":1440167924916,"type":"text","content":"It\'s a test!"}}';

var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: That gives SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: @Quentin: Should work fine now. I think while trying to indent the JSON, pressing the "enter"  key was causing the issue.