# Building JavaScript Array in C#, apostrophes changing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have done this to build JavaScript Arrays from int, double and string lists.

```
public string listToJsArray<T>(List<T> cslist)
    {
        bool numeric = true;
        if(
            !(typeof(T)==typeof(int)
            || typeof(T) == typeof(string)
            || typeof(T) == typeof(double))
            )
        {
            throw (new ArgumentException(message: "Only int, double and string are supported"));
        }
        if(typeof(T)==typeof(string))
        {
            numeric = false;
        }
        string JsArray = "[";

        for(int i=0;i<cslist.Count;i++)
        {
            string dataWithSurrendings = cslist[i].ToString();
            if(!numeric)
            {
                dataWithSurrendings = "'" + cslist[i].ToString() + "'";
            }
            if(i !=0)
            {
                dataWithSurrendings = "," + dataWithSurrendings;
            }
            if(i +1==cslist.Count)
            {
                dataWithSurrendings = dataWithSurrendings + "]";
            }
            JsArray += dataWithSurrendings;

        }

        return JsArray;
    }
```

My problem is when a list of strings is passed, apostrophes turn into `&#39;`.

for example, a list of `{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7"}` becomes this:
`[&#39;1&#39;,&#39;2&#39;,&#39;3&#39;,&#39;4&#39;,&#39;1&#39;,&#39;6&#39;,&#39;7&#39;]`

What modification is needed in this function, to return a correct array in JavaScript?

None of solutions did solve the problem. With JsonConvert I get almost same result. The problem is the single or double quote in View editor have not the same encoding as CS string.

Comment: Why not just use [JSON](http://www.json.org/) instead?

Comment: Specially, [NewtonSoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: **DON'T** - Take you original collection and serialize it to JSON. Now you have you Javascript array. JSON is a subset of Javascript so if you output something like `"var myArray = " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(csList) + ";"` you'll get what you need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single quotes within json value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143704/single-quotes-within-json-value)

Comment: @MattBurland you mean you have a JSON object with an array that can be parsed to a Javascript array? JSON != Javascript

Comment: @George: JSON is a subset of Javascript. Any JSON dropped into a `<script>` tag is valid Javascript. It doesn't even need to be parsed.

Comment: @MattBurland you're right, my bad. I was thinking the wrong way around

Comment: All I needed was @Html.Raw(). See Matt's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are doing this to drop into a webpage somewhere, something like:

```
<script>
    @{
        var output = listToJsArray(Model.SomeList);
    }
    var myArray = @Html.Raw(output);
    // some Javascript using that array
</script>
```

Don't waste your time trying to do it yourself. It's a pain and you are reinventing the wheel. JSON is valid Javascript and a serialization of an array into JSON is absolutely identical to a Javascript array literal. So use Javascript. JSON.Net is really useful here:

```
<script>
    @{
        var output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.SomeList);
    }
    var myArray = @Html.Raw(output);
    // some Javascript using that array
</script>
```

The serializer will handle all the annoying escaping, special characters and edge cases for you.

Comment: @Html.Raw alone solved my problem. of course your answer is totally correct.